# how to get UNIQUE value in tableau?

Tags: tableau-desktop

so I am trying to get the number of data points that have passed or failed based on their ID. However tableau only has COUNTD which does a distinct count and not a UNIQUE count (trust me this will out put two different numbers). Is there a function or formula to get the unique IDs?

One attempt I'm trying to do is count how many times an ID appears and only counting the ones that appeared once, but that is appearing more difficult than I thought. Any other suggestions would be helpful.

I've also tried an LOD function of `IF SUM{FIXED([ID]):COUNT([ID])}` but that didn't work out either.

Comment: Just as with SQL, COUNT(<field>) returns the number of records where <field> has a non-null value. COUNTD(<field>) returns the number of unique distinct values that appear in the <field> column, just like SQL's COUNT DISTINCT. That's all they do.

Comment: But when I do unique values in excel it only spits out the values that appear once. Distinct will spit out all the values no matter how many times it appears

Comment: Can you post a simple small table of sample input data, and an example table of what you'd like to compute - i.e. the correct answer for your example?